# Marklogic How to change directory name

Tags: xquery, marklogic

How to update directory from "/Collections/" to "/CollectionsCount/" in Marklogic

```
for $each in xdmp:directory("/collections/", "infinity")
return xdmp:node-uri($each)

result found:
 /collections/Count2017-08-25.xml
 /collections/Count2017-08-27.xml
 /collections/Count2017-08-26.xml
 /collections/Count2017-08-28.xml
```

I would like to update directory to become "/collectionsCount/" what function do I use. Thanks in advance.

```
 /collectionsCount/Count2017-08-25.xml
/collectionsCount/Count2017-08-26.xml
....
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Directories are a construct based on a document's URI, so in order to change the directories, you will need to delete the old documents and insert new ones at new URIs (using the new directory prefix in place of the old one).

```
for $each in xdmp:directory("/collections/", "infinity")
let $old-uri := $each/xdmp:node-uri(.)
let $permissions := xdmp:document-get-permissions($old-uri)
let $collections := xdmp:document-get-collections($old-uri)
let $quality := xdmp:document-get-quality($old-uri)
let $properties := xdmp:document-properties($old-uri)
let $new-uri := concat('/collectionsCount/', substring-after($old-uri, '/collections/'))
return (
  xdmp:document-insert($new-uri, $each, $permissions, $collections, $quality),
  xdmp:document-set-properties($new-uri, $properties),
  xdmp:document-delete($old-uri))
```

**Edit:** Updated to include @hunterhacker's suggestion to propagate document metadata. Note that I intentionally left out assigning the new document to the old document's forest, since in most cases I assume it's better to let the database decide.

Comment: The new DMSDK in ML9 has an easy way of ensuring such an operation can scale, as once you hit thousands of URIs, the operation may timeout in qconsole. See https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle/wiki/DMSDK-Tasks for examples on how to easily use DMSDK in Gradle too.

Comment: Production code should also copy over metadata like collections, security, document quality, properties, etc.